# Find the locus of points whose distances from the line $y=\sqrt3x$ and x-axis are equal.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, locus

Find the locus of points whose distances from the line$\hspace{0.2cm}$ $y=\sqrt3x$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ and x-axis are equal.

My solution:I start with the following $$\frac{|\sqrt3x_1-y_1|}{2}=\frac{|y_1|}{1}$$
After squaring both sides and simplification I got finally $$3x_1^2-3y_1^2-2\sqrt3x_1y_1=0$$ 
By comparing with $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$
In my problem I have $$B^2-4AC=12+36=48>0$$
So it should be a hyperbola,infact a rectangular hyperbola(because $A+C=0$).

My Problem:If we think geometrically then the line$\hspace{0.2cm}$ $y=\sqrt3x$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$has angle$\hspace{0.2cm}$ $60^o$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$with x-axis.So geometrically the locus off all the points whose distances from the line $\hspace{0.2cm}$$y=\sqrt3x$ $\hspace{0.2cm}$and x-axis are equal should be a line making angle $\hspace{0.2cm}$$30^o$$\hspace{0.2cm}$ with x-axis.
So please someone help me to find out the locus.

Thanks.

Comment: The distance between the point $(x_1,y_1)$ and the line $y=\sqrt3 x$ is not $|\sqrt3 x_1-y_1|$. You have to find the distance from the point to the line by finding the perpendicular going through that point.

Comment: @ryagami the distance of $(x_1,y_1)$ from $ax+by+c=0$ is $$d=\frac{|ax_1+by_1+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

Comment: is this wrong??

Comment: Yes, that is correct, sorry.

Comment: Yes it's a rectangular hyperbola. You just missed the fact that it is degenerate in two orthogonal straight lines (the bissectrices of the angle!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the answer is two lines $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt 3},y=-\sqrt 3x$ because 
$$0=3x^2-3y^2-2\sqrt 3xy=(x-\sqrt 3y)(\sqrt 3y+3x).$$

Comment: So why we can not use the discriminant $B^2-4AC$.I understand that it is reducible but What is problem with the discriminant?

Comment: @Math: My understanding is that if $B^2-4AC\gt 0$, then it is either hyperbola or $2$ intersecting lines.

Answer (score 1):

$$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ will be degenerate conic if

$$\begin{vmatrix} a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c\end{vmatrix}=0$$

and it will represent a pair of straight lines real or imaginary according as $ab-h^2\le0$ or $>0$

Ellipse, Parabola & Hyperbola are all [non-degenerate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Discriminant) conics

Comment: @Math,Have you heard of degenerate conics?